# How to capture textarea values efficiently in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

My component below has 3 function, each for storing the value of a textarea inside a variable.
Given that I have 3 different textareas, how can I rewrite the code below in order to make it more DRY and still store the values in 3 distinct variables(value1, value2, value3).

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

value1 = '';
value2 = '';
value3 = '';

textareaInput1(e) {
  const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const value1 = element.value;
}

textareaInput2(e) {
  const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const value2 = element.value;
}

textareaInput3(e) {
  const element = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
  const value3 = element.value;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea (input)="textareaInput1($event)"></textarea>
<textarea (input)="textareaInput2($event)"></textarea>
<textarea (input)="textareaInput3($event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `[(ngModel)]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you use it like this

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="value1"></textarea>
```